# Need to use a text input to answer prompts instead of a dialog box

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a text based game. What I am wanting to do is make a text input that could be used to answer the prompts(Like Zork). I do not want the prompt dialog boxes coming up because 1) they can get annoying for users and 2) When they come up, they freeze the webpage until they are answered. I have not personally heard of a way to make this work, so if anyone out there can help me out, that would be amazing.

Below is a small section of the game including 3 of the prompts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
#game {
    width:1100
}
body {background-color:black}
p {color:white}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="game">
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var seed = prompt("What kind of potato do you want to be? A RUSSET POTATO, RED POTATO, or SWEET POTATO?")
        switch(seed) {
            case 'RUSSET POTATO' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Hot diggity! You became a Russet Potato!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            case 'RED POTATO' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Greetings comrade! Welcome to the potatoes of Soviet Socialist Republics!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            case 'SWEET POTATO' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Hey there sweet thing! You're such a Sweet Potato!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            default:
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Make sure you are spelling your answers correctly and typing them in all caps!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
                //Revert to prompt
        }

        var soil = prompt("What type of soil will you be planted in? PODZOL, STUTTGART, RED, AKADAMA, or CLAY?");
        switch(soil) {
            case 'PODZOL' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("There are many minerals, but the acid is ruining the shell of your seed! You die an agonizing and slow death.");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
                //link to lose page
            break;
            case 'STUTTGART' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Your seed is nice and cozy in its new home. Happy growing!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            case 'RED' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Good choice comrade, but communism isn't always the best choice. Getting water will be a bit difficult.");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            case 'AKADAMA' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("It will be a bit difficult to grown roots, but you are a tough little seed! Hope you can grow well!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            case 'CLAY' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("A hard rain comes in and your potato drowns.");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
                //link to lose page
            break;
            default:
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Make sure you are spelling your answers correctly and typing them in all caps!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
                //Revert to prompt
        }

        var power = prompt("What do you wish to do now? SPROUT TUBERS, add DISEASE CONTROL, or THICKEN SKIN?");
        switch(power) {
            case 'SPROUT TUBERS' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("You will surely grow happily with this decison!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            case 'DISEASE CONTROL' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Your growth won't be as plentiful, but you won't face as much risk from disease now!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            case 'THICKEN SKIN' :
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("You are a very self-concious potato. You desire a thick skin to avoid being bullied by your fellow potatoes. Don't worry, you will be their supreme leader eventually! I assure you!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
            break;
            default:
                var para = document.createElement("p");
                var node = document.createTextNode("Make sure you are spelling your answers correctly and typing them in all caps!");
                para.appendChild(node);

                var element = document.getElementById("game");
                element.appendChild(para);
        }

    }
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you everyone in advance! This is my first attempt at coding something and it is quite the experience even though it seems fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

input elements would work well here.

```
<input id="theInputBox" type="text>
```

That will put an input box on the screen that the user can type into.

To check the text in the input box, do `document.getElementById('theInputBox').value`

Congrats on your first attempt at coding! I think making games is a great way to learn to code.